# is there any way to send sms or email to user without using server in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to allow me to send an "sms" or "email messages" to the users without using the server ?
I was looking for some free API that can help to achieve this I don't have a server....so how can I do it in a flutter ?

I tried using  `email_auth` in flutter but it's asking for server configurations and some of the methods from google but haven't gotten the solution

Comment: Why don't you use Share capabilities and send the data via whatever the use chooses, be it email (via systems Email app), text message (via systems messenger) or any other choice available

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, since your app is only responsible for the client part, and any authentication should be done on the server.

A good alternative if you don't have a server is to use BaaS (Back-end As A Service), basically the back-end to create your application, but in the cloud.

Here's a small list of popular BaaS back-ends for Flutter:

- Firebase
- AWS Amplify
- AppWrite